# Emulating $near with some other geospatial queries mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

So I cannot do an $or or $and action with $near since mongodb 2.6, is there any way of emulating that?

```
db.places.find({$or: [{loc: {$near: [50,50]}}, {rating: {$gt: 3}}])
```

Since the above code is not possible can I replace $near with some other queries like $geoWithin or $geometry to get the same or similar results?

EDIT:

I found

```
db.places.find({$or: [{loc: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [50,50], 100}}}, {rating: {$gt: 3}}])
```

Is this somehow same provided I use $maxDistance in first example

Comment: Well a `$geoWithin` with a `$centreSphere` is relatively the same ( as you just mentioned ) but the difference being of course that there is no "sort" or projection option of a distance available. You can always run two queries and combine the results. Methods to do that vary depending on your language implementation. Also, only use the the `$and: []` form is not allowed since query arguments are not top level operatrors. All general query conditions in MongoDB are already "and" statements, and allowed. You should rarely need the first form

Comment: thanks for the answer mate